# Gives access to root user for a period of time

Tags: users, root

I want to know if it's possible to give access to root user for one week or a month, for example.

It's possible to increase the period of time before the defined period ends?
Is it possible to give access without time limitation, forever?

Comment: Does the user require *root* access?  Or just elevated privileges for specific tasks?  As @Gilles mentioned, once you give someone root, there's really no way to guarantee that you can take it back.  You'd be better served putting the effort into designing a role account, or a sudo profile that provides exactly the required privileges, with nothing extra.

Comment: The user must have access to the root user for a period of time. Not user with rights like root for a period of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you can add and remove users at will from sudoers, all you need is a way to schedule it.

One way you could do this is to do something like this with sudoers:

- Edit `/etc/sudoers` using `sudo visudo`, and add a statement for that user with a unique string on the end:

```
username ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

- Schedule this line to be removed in one month. My preferred way would be to use `at` if you have it (it's bundled with `atd`), but you can also schedule it manually using `cron`:

```
at now + 1 month <<< "sed -i '/^username ALL=(ALL) ALL$/d' /etc/sudoers"
```

Comment: However note that there is absolutely no guarantee that this removes the user's root access. As soon as you grant root access to a user, the user can plant a backdoor which will give him root access forever, and there's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: @Gilles That's true, although there's not many ways I can think of to mitigate that. Realistically, you shouldn't be giving anyone root access that you don't trust in the first place.